# Can't search into heap using gdb

Tags: linux, gdb, heap-memory, gdbserver

I try to search ascii in heap memory , I check the heap address using

```
cat /proc/PID/maps | grep heap
```

Then wirh GDB  I want to search ascii

```
find 0x1577000,0x2a01000,"/bin/sh"
```

But I got error:

```
gdbserver: Unable to access target memory at 0x1579e9b, halting search.
```

What can I do please?

Answer (score 0):

> But I got error:

1. You *probably* used `grep` and `(gdb) find` on different processes. Heap location is randomized by ASLR (though GDB disables ASLR)
2. In GLIBC, `malloc` tends to use `mmap`ed arenas, which are *not* marked as `heap` in `/proc/$pid/maps`, so there is a high chance you wouldn't find the string you are looking for anyway.

Comment: So how can I know by looking at `/proc/PID/maps` all the memory area that belong to heap?

Answer (score 0):

##### parameters for the find command

> find 0x1577000,0x2a01000,"/bin/sh"

GDB's *find* command will search, in the words of its documentation, an "inclusive range". But if 0x2a01000 is the upper bound of a memory region in `/proc/pid/maps`, it means the region goes up to but does not include that location. So subtract 1 from that, and give GDB the command

```
find 0x1577000,0x2a00fff,"/bin/sh"
```

---

##### where does glibc's *malloc* place things

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LLEN 1024
int bssvar;
int datavar = 1;

char *lookupmap(void *addr) {
        static char line[LLEN];
        FILE *f = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
        while (fgets(line, LLEN, f) != NULL) {
                void *start = NULL, *end = NULL;
                sscanf(line, "%p-%p", &start, &end);
                if (addr >= start && addr < end) {
                        fclose(f);
                        return line;
                }
        }
        fclose(f);
        return "\n";
}

int main() {
        for (int i = 21; i >= 0; i--) {
                char *addr = malloc(1<<i);
                printf("%2d %p %s", i, addr, lookupmap(addr));
        }
        printf("bssvar  %p %s", &bssvar, lookupmap(&bssvar));
        printf("datavar %p %s", &datavar, lookupmap(&datavar));
}
```

Its output in 32-bit mode on Ubuntu 22.10:

```
21 0xf79ff010 f79ff000-f7c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
20 0xf7eac010 f7eac000-f7faf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
19 0xf797e010 f797e000-f7c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
18 0xf7e6b010 f7e6b000-f7faf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
17 0xf7e4a010 f7e4a000-f7faf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
16 0x5785e2f0 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
15 0x5786e300 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
14 0x57876310 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
13 0x5787a320 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
12 0x5787c330 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
11 0x5787d340 5785d000-5787e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
10 0x5787db50 5785d000-5789f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 9 0x5787df60 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 8 0x5787e170 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 7 0x5787e280 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 6 0x5787e310 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 5 0x5787e360 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 4 0x5787e390 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 3 0x5787e3b0 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 2 0x5787e3c0 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 1 0x5787e3d0 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
 0 0x5787e3e0 5785d000-5789e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0   [heap]
bssvar  0x56654040 56654000-56655000 rw-p 00003000 08:00 681675 /home/mp/m3-32
datavar 0x56654008 56654000-56655000 rw-p 00003000 08:00 681675 /home/mp/m3-32
```

So you want to look in the `[heap]` region, which is where addresses from *sbrk* come from and is just above the data segment, as well as all regions that have perms `rw-p` and no backing file (allocated by  *mmap* with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`).