# How does GDB know where the heap is allocated

Tags: gdb, heap-memory

In GDB, running `info proc mappings` dumps the address space of the target, including the heap. My question is, how does GDB know where the heap is allocated? Obviously, something like `malloc` returns an address, but it does not specify the exact heap start address or its allocated size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging a live process on Linux, GDB's `info proc mappings` command parses the `/proc/pid/maps` file - which contains the details of a process's memory regions - then formats and displays the information. If the *pathname* field of an entry in the maps file says `[heap]`, that's what GDB will display.

The Linux kernel's [implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L333). of `/proc/pid/maps` will show `[heap]` on the line corresponding to the memory region that contains the address known as the *break*, which historically has been the top of the data segment. The break can be moved to higher or lower addresses by using the *sbrk* system call.

glibc's *malloc* uses the heap for small allocations. For larger allocations, it calls *mmap* with anonymous backing, and you can see these memory regions in the maps file - they have no *pathname* field.

I've written a small program which calls *malloc* to allocate memory in a variety of sizes, then displays the memory region where each allocation was placed. It's in my answer to [Can't search into heap using gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036898/2554472).